# Does MicroLite ORM support DynamicObject / IDynamicObjectMetaProvider

Tags: c#, dynamicobject, micro-orm

I'm looking for a micro orm system supporting DynamicObject / IDynamicObjectMetaProvider structures, e.g.:

```
public class VirtualTest : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return _properties[propertyName];
        }
        set
        {
            _properties[propertyName] = value;
        }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return _properties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _properties[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Populating with:

```
var sessionFactory = Configure.Fluently()
            .ForMsSql2005Connection("TestDB", str, "System.Data.SqlClient").CreateSessionFactory();

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var query = new SqlQuery("SELECT 1 AS TestField");
        var result = session.Fetch<VirtualTest>(query);
    }
}
```

It just throws a `MicroLiteException` with additional information `System.Object`.

Does MicroLite support such objects?

Comment: Checking the code, there appears to be [*explicit* support for `ExpandoObject`](https://github.com/TrevorPilley/MicroLite/blob/c28b82e0bc8275609d81ed113eb955a4214c6440/MicroLite/Mapping/ObjectInfo.cs#L115), but no mention of other DLR support